# What kind of flying insect is this?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

What kind of flying insect is this? It kinda resembles a dragonfly but it had what looked like a stinger on the end of it's tail. It was found in Franklin, Ohio.

[image]

Comment: Better provide some visuals, else it will be very difficult to identify.

Comment: The OP did add an image, however, they didn't add the reference. I suggested an edit that does reveal the image of the dragonfly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ... it kinda resembles a dragonfly ...

That's because it *is* a dragonfly! This is a female *[Tramea onusta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-mantled_saddlebags)*, most commonly known as a "Red Saddlebag", which comes from the red coloration found at the lower regions of the dragonfly's hindwings.

> ... it had what looked like a stinger on the end of it's tail.

That's exactly correct! Female dragonflies have what look to be a stinger, however, they're used for laying eggs instead (and not as a weapon). ([source](http://nwdragonflier.blogspot.com/2010/12/do-dragonflies-bite-or-sting.html), p.5)

[image: Tramea onusta1]

[image]

[image]